# To which Hadith is this statement of Imam Shafi'i attributed?

Tags: hadith, authenticity, reference-request, books

I have found a statement that Imam Shafi'i would have said:

( سُئل الامام الشافعي رحمه الله تعالى : "كيف يكون سوء الظن بالله؟ قال: الوسوسة، والخوف الدائم من وقوع مُصِيبَة، وترقب زوال النعمة، كلها من سوء الظن بالرحمن الرحيم )

Translation: Imam Shafi'i, rahimullah ta'ala, was asked: 'What is the mistrust of Allah? He said: Waswas, constant fear of calamity, and anticipation of the demise of grace, all of it is mistrust of the Most Merciful, the Most Merciful.'

---

On the internet, it is labeled to be a Hadith related in [Hilyat al-Awliya](https://shamela.ws/book/10495) with the reference number (9/123), but it is nowhere to be found in the book. Maybe it is a mistake from those who are quoting it, so I would like to ask if somebody has knowledge about this statement, it's source and authenticity?

Comment: Are you sure they didn't just mean Hadith as in narration from someone?

Comment: It is referenced as being narrated in Hilyat al-Awliya (9/123), which is not there.

Comment: Hilyat al-Awliya seems to be a book that quotes famous scholars, not a hadith book.

Comment: Also could you mention where you found it referenced like this?

Comment: It also quotes narrations from the Prophet (ﷺ)

Comment: https://majles.alukah.net/t157437-179/

Comment: The statements meaning actually is incorrect because even prophet's had such feelings as the qur'an states.